# Rails Omniauth missing required parameter: code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth, google-oauth

Running rails 3.2.18 on c9.io, and I have the gems omniauth and omniauth-google-oauth2 installed.  I ran into a problem where I would get a CSRF error on the callback, and it sounded like adding "provider_ignores_state: true" to the params would prevent that, at least for testing and development. It did get rid of the CSRF error, but now there is a new error:

```
OAuth2::Error

invalid_request: Missing required parameter: code
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Missing required parameter: code"
}
```

my config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, "clientID", "clientSecret",
    scope: 'profile', image_aspect_ratio: 'square', image_size: 48, access_type: 'online', name: 'google', provider_ignores_state: true
end
```

Top few lines from the trace:

```
oauth2 (1.0.0) lib/oauth2/client.rb:113:in `request'
oauth2 (1.0.0) lib/oauth2/client.rb:138:in `get_token'
oauth2 (1.0.0) lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:29:in `get_token'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:93:in `build_access_token'
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.6) lib/omniauth/strategies/google_oauth2.rb:77:in `custom_build_access_token'
```

EDIT:
Adding the versions for the gems

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/omniauth-1.2.2
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/omniauth-google-oauth2-0.2.6
```

Comment: So I narrowed it down some: I set up an identical rails app but running rails 4.x, and it works. No CSRF errors, no missing parameter errors. What is different between 3.2 and 4 that changes the way CSRF prevention works?

Comment: Update again, upgraded the app that was giving me problems to rails 4.1.6 and still have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the view! I was trying to use /auth/google/callback when it should have just been /auth/google.
Took way too long to figure that one out...